# Parse big XML in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I need to parse pretty big XML in PHP (like 300 MB). How can i do it most effectively?

In particular, i need to locate the specific tags and extract their content in a flat TXT file, nothing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's one or few time job I'd use [XML Starlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/). But if you really want to do it PHP side then I'd recommend to preparse it to smaller chunks and then processing it. If you load it via [DOM](http://php.net/DOM) as one big chunk it will take **a lot** of memory. Also use CLI side PHP script to speed things up.

Answer (score 10):

You can read and parse XML in chunks with an old-school [SAX-based parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML) approach using PHP's [xml parser functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php).

Using this approach, there's no real limit to the size of documents you can parse, as you simply read and parse a buffer-full at a time. The parser will fire events to indicate it has found tags, data etc.

There's a [simple exampl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/example.xml-structure.php)e in the manual which shows how to pick up start and end of tags. For your purposes you might also want to use [xml_set_character_data_handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xml-set-character-data-handler.php) so that you pick up on the text between tags also.

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient way to do that is to create static XSLT and apply it to your XML using [`XSLTProcessor`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.xsltprocessor.php). The method names are a bit misleading. Even though you want to output plain text, you should use either [`transformToXML()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.transformtoxml.php) if you need is as a string variable, or [`transformToURI()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.transformtouri.php) if you want to write a file.

Answer (score 1):

This is what SAX was designed for. SAX has a low memory footprint reading in a small buffer of data and firing events when it encounter elements, character data etc.

It is not always obvious how to use SAX, well it wasn't to me the first time I used it but in essence you have to maintain your own state and view as to where you are within the document structure so generally you will end up with variables describing what section of the document you are in e.g. inFoo, inBar etc which you set when you encounter particular start/end elements.

There is a short description and example of a sax parser [here](http://www.joemarini.com/tutorials/tutorialpages/listoflinks.php)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your memory requirements, you can either load it up and [parse it with XSLT](http://us.php.net/xslt) (the memory-consuming route), or you can create a [forward-only cursor](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php) and walk the tree yourself, printing the values you're looking for (the memory-efficient route).

Answer (score 0):

Pull parsing is the way to go. This way it's memory-efficient AND easy to process. I have been processing files that are as large as 50 Mb or more.